# Calculate/Derive first Start Date in continuous date spans

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I am using Postgres and I am trying to wrap my head around on how exactly I could derive the first start date in continuous date spans. For example :-

```
ID | Start Date | End Date
==========================
1|2020-01-01|2020-01-31
1|2020-02-01|2020-03-31
1|2020-05-01|2020-06-30
1|2020-07-01|2020-07-31
1|2020-08-01|2020-08-31
```

The output I am expecting is

```
ID | Start Date | End Date | Continous Date
===========================================
1|2020-01-01|2020-01-31|2020-01-01
1|2020-02-01|2020-03-31|2020-01-01
1|2020-05-01|2020-06-30|2020-05-01
1|2020-07-01|2020-07-31|2020-05-01
1|2020-08-01|2020-08-31|2020-05-01
```

Basically it should give me the the very first start date of a continuous date span.

Appreciate your inputs or directions on how i could go about this. CTE's unfortunately is something which I might not be able to go with.

Answer (score 1):

This is a gaps and island problem, where islands are defined as a group of consecutive records with contiguous dates. You want the start of each island.

Here is an approach that uses `lag()` to retrieve the "previous" end date, and then builds the group with a cumulative `sum()` that increments on every gap.

```
select t.*, 
    min(start_date) over(partition by id, grp order by start_date) continous_date
from (
    select t.*, 
        count(*) filter(where start_date is distinct from lag_end_date + interval '1 day') over(partiton by id order by start_date) grp
    from (
        select t.*, 
            lag(end_date) over(partition by id order by start_date) lag_end_date
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  Basically, determine where there is an overlap, using `lag()` or some other function.  Then the "islands" are identified by a cumulative sum of the non-overlaps.  I would approach this as:

```
select t.*,
       min(start_date) over (partition by id, grp) as continuous_start_date
from (select t.*,
             count(*) filter (where prev_end_date is null or prev_end_date < start_date - interval '1 day') as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   max(end_date) over (partition by id order by start_date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_end_date
            from t
           ) t
     ) t;
```

Note that this handles overlaps between adjoining records as well as starts on the day before.